# RabbitVCS doesn't update a folder that was checked out with no recursion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I checked out a directory from RabbitVCS without recursion and that worked fine.  Now I want to update the directory recursively so that it is up to date with the repository.  RabbitVCS simply says the folder is up to date when I try to update.  There is no option to check out the folder I want now.

I can checkout recursively using subversion from the command line, but I'd really like to know how to allow RabbitVCS do it.

Comment: Why have you made the original checkout without recursion? Can't you do it with recursion and then run SVN update?